# How to know when an item in cache expires in django

Tags: django, caching, redis, e-commerce, memcached

I'm currently building an order and checkout system for an application in django. I need to know when an order expires in a cache to trigger a code that returns items back to the inventory,up till now i haven't made progress in knowing how to do this in django.
I just need a way to trigger a code after item expires in cache similar to signals for db save and delete.

Comment: which CacheBackend you use?

Comment: i'm using redis

Comment: What do you think about a cron scheduled command?